# Why does margin-top affect the placement of an absolute div?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z4062jfn/ - with absolute positioning. I didn't expect any margin values given to the divs to affect their absolute position. And this is true for a margin-bottom value given to the top div (uncomment line 8 of CSS).  But a margin-top value given to the bottom box (uncomment line 19 of CSS) *does* move the bottom div position down by that amount.

What is there in  this situation that lets a margin rule override an absolute position rule - sometimes?

```
<div id="box1"><p>box 1</p></div>
<div id="box2"><p>box 2</p></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple factual explanation for why this happens is that the offset properties `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` actually respect the corresponding margin properties on each side. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props) says that these properties specify how far the *margin edge* of a box is offset from that particular side. The margin edge is defined in [section 8.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-dimensions).

So, when you set a top offset, the top margin is taken into account, and when you set a left offset, the left margin is taken into account.

If you had set the bottom offset instead of the top, you'll see that the bottom margin takes effect. If you then try to set a top margin, the top margin will no longer have any effect.

If you set *both* the top and bottom offsets, and *both* top and bottom margins, *and* a height, then the values become over-constrained and the bottom offset has no effect (and in turn neither does the bottom margin).

If you're looking to understand *why the spec defines offsets this way*, rather than why browsers behave this way, then it's primarily opinion-based, because all you'll get is conjecture. That said, [Fabio's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944865/why-does-margin-top-affect-the-placement-of-an-absolute-div/25945016#25945016) is quite reasonable.

Comment: This explanation is clearest for me. The spec says that for absolute elements,  top places the edge of the _top margin_, not the edge of the element top. And similarly, bottom places the edge of the _bottom margin_ not the bottom edge of the element. That makes it clear.  But while these margin values will affect the initial, absolute placement of the elements, they never fulfill their normal role as _margins_, because, of course, the absolute positioning lifts the absolute elements out of the normal flow.  The margins don't exist for the elements themselves.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because an absolutely positioned box is removed from the normal flow and is assigned a position with respect to the containing block. If you don't define a containing block, then it's `body`.

So, with that in mind, think of the containing block as a coordinates axis that starts at top left. If you give your element this properties:

```
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
```

just like you did, you will have leave an empty space above and left, thus, if you apply margin-top or margin-left, it will work, because your elements are capable to virtually go through every pixel of both axises up to that 100px top and 100px left position, and same applies for negative margins. However, since `position:absolute` removes the element from the flow and any impact on any subsequent sibling element, it's easy to see that nothing can happen after the element "finishes", hence margin-bottom and margin-right won't work since they don't have anything to get margin from.

I have made an image to show the behavior since my explanation might be a bit obscure

[image]

Comment: If you don't define a containing block, it's the initial containing block, not `body`. Note also that bottom and right margins can and do have an effect on the absposed box itself (again, not any other in-flow boxes) if you set the bottom and right offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Your `margin bottom` is not working since you put the `top` property in your divs. Remove `top` and your `margin bottom` will work for your `#box1`.

Comment: This does not explain *why* it happens, it just states the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Margin-bottom affect too. See the code below, if you set a bottom reference in #box1 it will apply 20px in margin-bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/t5ooot7u/

```
#box1 {
    width:200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:gold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:230px;
    left:100px;
    margin-bottom:20px;

}
```