# Aligning images top-left, center, and bottom-right

Tags: css, image, alignment

I want to place the images in a div like shown on the diagram. One should be aligned to top-left, one aligned to center-center, and one aligned to bottom-right. The width and gap also needs to be resized based on the window size. What would be the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just use position styling and this will work.

```css
<style type="text/css">
  div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #img1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  #img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #img3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div>
  <img id ="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
  <img id ="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
  <img id ="img3" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
</div>
```

Comment: You could also target the images with [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Comment: Small followup question–when we run this code, why is the height of div 0?

Comment: Because of the content's position is absolute.

Comment: @SeanDKim without specifying a size for the div, its height is just big enough to contain the elements inside of it. However, absolutely positioned elements don't take up any space. All of the images inside the div are absolutely positioned and there's nothing else in it.

Comment: I learned something new from this answer. I really thought that if you set the top, bottom, left, and right, the image would be stretched the same way as other elements are (http://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/mONWvr). This confuses me a little, too. None of those values are actually respected, but the margin setting doesn't work without them.

Comment: In your codepen code the green color which you are getting for entire screen because the div is not having any width and height. So if you want to replicate the current behavior just try to assign width and height to the div.

Comment: @aavrug That CodePen was supposed to show the behavior I (mistakenly) expected. I thought the image would stretch to the entire window just like that green div in the pen does, but I was wrong. I figured out how/why this is from a couple of different sources, though... MDN: https://diigo.com/0988jt (the height / width is constrained by the image's actual size) & This SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25945053/2948042 (the positions act on the element's *margin edge*, not the edge of the element itself). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should `position: absolute` all the images with respect to the viewport.

This is what you are looking for:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 40px;
}
.first {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.second {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.third {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="first" src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
  <img class="second" src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
  <img class="third" src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend a different approach... Flexbox! It's much easier, but it's a newer CSS feature.

CSS-Tricks guide to Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flexbox support table at CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Now, this solution seems to work just fine on CodePen (http://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/rWXjbY) in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason it breaks in the "Run code snippet" window here on SO. Hopefully, that's just a problem here.

**Update**: It only worked on CodePen. Most of these playgrounds (with the exception of CodePen) inject code into the document after my code. `img:last-child` didn't match anything because the last child of the body was a `<script>` block. In any case, it's probably bad practice to use the `body` element as a container this way. This is fixed now, and should work everywhere.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 33%;
  max-height: 33%;
}

img:first-child {
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
      align-self: flex-start;
}

img:last-child {
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="cat1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/1">
<img alt="cat1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/2">
<img alt="cat1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/3">
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't think your last image is little misplaced.

Comment: @aavrug I noticed that right away. I thought it was a peculiarity here on SO, but I've recreated on jsfiddle and cssdeck. Apparently, it only works on CodePen. I think there's still a flexbox-based solution, but I must have an error in my code somewhere.

Comment: After adding ```align-self:flex-end``` seems working fine.

Comment: @aavrug Problem solved. It's not a good idea to use the `body` element as a flexbox container the way I was doing. Most of these *playgrounds* (with the exception of CodePen) append code to the body after my code. So, there was no element that matched `img:last-child` the last child here, and on jsfiddle and on cssdeck is a `<script>` block.

Comment: Yes I was solving but then I had seen that you updated :P

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use **Bootstrap 4** can do this trick:

- [`align-self-*`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment): Control the vertical alignment of a specified flex item.
- [`img-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/#responsive-images): Make your images responsive.

```css
.row {
  height: 30rem;
  border: .1rem red solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col align-self-start">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/200x250/ff9999&text=img1">
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-center">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/200x250/ffb3b3&text=img2">
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-end">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/200x250/ffcccc&text=img3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```